# Error 302 Google Sheets PHP SDK

Tags: php, google-sheets

I've been trying to add listElements to a listFeed and it's working. The problem is after some requests i get an error message : Error in Google Request (Error code: 302). I've searched alot of places, but i couldn't find an answer. Here is my code :

```
    //Google initialization

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(GAPPID);
    $client->setClientSecret(GAPPSECRET);
    $client->refreshToken(GAPPREFRESHTOKEN);
    $auth = $client->getAccessToken();
    $tokenResponse = json_decode($auth);
    $gToken = $tokenResponse->access_token;

    //Getting the list feed

    $serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($gToken);
    ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);
    $spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
    $spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();
    $spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle($gConfig["spreadsheetTitle"]);
    $worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();
    $worksheet = $worksheetFeed->getByTitle($gConfig["worksheetTitle"]);
    $listFeed = $worksheet->getListFeed();

    //Adding list elements to sheet

    for($i = 0;$i <= 1000; $i++){
        $listFeed->insert(array('col1Header' => 'test'));
    }
```

Do you have any idea where this error comes from ? Does the sheet api have a limited no. requests/hour. Still, it doesn't makes sense even if it has a limit cap, because when I run the script the second time, it still works but until a different point. I assure you that I configurated the maximum execution time, so that won't be a problem.

What i've tried till now:

1. Using CellFeed instead of ListFeed
2. Connecting to the api everytime I insert a list element (even refreshing the access token and getting the listfeed again).

None of those work. They behave the same.
Here is the link for the SDK : https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client

I hope someone will help me find a solution.

Thanks,
Andrei

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing this error. I've just run the above 3 times now, entering 1000 records in each run and it has completed successfully each time!